# Laravel Cartalyst Sentinel - Can't extend EloquentUser

Tags: laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

I've so trouble adding columns to users table with Sentinel.

What I did :

- Creating my own migration file to add (for now) 1 column : "adress"
- Creating a class "User" in app/Http/Controller

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;


    use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;

    class User extends EloquentUser {

        protected $fillable = [
            'email',
            'password',
            'last_name',
            'first_name',
            'permissions',
            'adresse',
        ];


    }
```

- Changing the model in config/cartalyst.sentinel.php

  ```
  'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser',
  ```

  to

  ```
  'model' => 'App\Http\Controllers\User',
  ```

But, adresse stay empty in database.

I've tried my code with

```
     $credentials = [
            'email'    => 'john.dode@example.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'adresse' => 'password',
        ];

        $user = Sentinel::create($credentials);
        dd($user);
```

And the result of `dd($user)` is :

```
EloquentUser {#392 ▼


 #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:5 [▼
    0 => "email"
    1 => "password"
    2 => "last_name"
    3 => "first_name"
    4 => "permissions"
  ]
  [...]
```

I don't want to add my fields in the vendors, but it's the only solutions working right now ...

Edit : I've tried to follow EXACTLY this https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/wiki/Extending-Sentinel but same result here ...

**UPDATE**

My problem seem to be deeper than expected ...
If I change \vendor\cartalyst\sentinel\src\config\config.php it's working pretty well. So my config/cartalyst.sentinel.php is completly ignore by Sentinel ...

Thanks guys !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok ... so, I figured out what was the issue thanks to [Laravel Sentinel referencing the wrong config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405749/laravel-sentinel-referencing-the-wrong-config-file)

I was using

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel;
```

instead of

```
use Sentinel;
```

So, I was just following the doc ... great job !

Answer (score 1):

May be this can be helpful: `php artisan config:cache`